# Can we get write access to user favorites?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, api-v2

I'd like users of my app to be able to add questions to their favourites.

Will this be added to the API as an authenticated call?

Comment: this should be for 2.1 or something as a pilot of a proper write API

Answer (score 1):

All write access is deferred until a future release, V2.0 is just adding authentication (and more read-only stuff, naturally).