# Add close-vote information to the questions object

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, api-v2, voting

Would it be possible to add [close/reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) vote information to the [questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) object?

For example, you usually see something along the lines of:

```
close (3)
```

when a question has three (current) close-votes.  Can we get access to this in the API, maybe display the *number* of close-votes and possibly the types suggested (i.e. Not Constructive, Not a Real Question, etc).

Comment: I also would like to see this implemented. It would even be better if you would allow us to do close vote using the API.

Comment: @PeeHaa I believe _write_ access will be allowed in a future version of the API, [not just  yet](http://stackapps.com/a/3095/9533).

Comment: Note that, as of now, this information (# of close votes) has been available from the API for quite some time.

Answer (score 7):

I'll slot this in for v2.1, not super useful in general but definitely interesting information that we should make available.

Comment: Wait - v2.1? - would it be possible to get a brief summary of what that will include?

Comment: @George - no, it's just in the "writing things down to remember to include" stage not an active development one.

Comment: But it's safe to assume that it will not support writing data (scheduled for v3.0), correct?

Comment: @George - eh, 2.1 may become 3.0 (with implied write access); depends on scheduling, available resources, and what not.  Far too early to say definitively.

Comment: @KevinMontrose The close vote *count* is available now... any plans for the pre-closure *reasons*?